# Read passive RFID key tags

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I have passive RFID key tag [image]
.

In its description I saw that this tag is passive RFID tag, and it working on NfcA protocol (ISO 14443), and it working with NFC and NXP.

I tried to read its ID to my smartphone, but it didn't recognize it, and I don't know why.
This RFID tag should be recognize in my smartphone.

I want to read his ID and teach my smartphone to send that ID (In other words, that my smartphone will be also RFID).

Is that possible? This tag should be recognized by my smartphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) reading the tag's ID**

That depends on whether the tag is supported by the phone.

If the tag is ISO 14443 Type A (NfcA) it will most likely work with your phone. In that case you should hear the "NFC sound" when you tap the tag. (One exception: if your tag is MIFARE Classic and your phone is a Samsung phone with Broadcom NFC chipset, e.g. the Galaxy S4: with this combination you will see a "This tag is not supported" error message when you tap the tag. In that case you cannot read the tags ID.)

If the tag is ISO 1443 Type B (NfcB) there are known issues with many tags. E.g. tags are not properly recognized, some tags are incompatible with some NFC chipsets, etc.

---

**(2) clone the tag ID to your phone**

No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

From [Michael Roland's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19777553/1435247) answer:

> (One exception: if your tag is MIFARE Classic and your phone is a Samsung phone with 
>   Broadcom NFC chipset, e.g. the Galaxy S4: with this combination you will see a "This tag 
>   is not supported" error message when you tap the tag. In that case you cannot read the tags ID.

There seems to be mixed reporting regarding this. Here are two sources that suggest partial support in that the ID's can be read:

http://www.rfid-blog.com/?p=2247

http://www.andytags.com/nfc-tags-compatibility-issues.html#.Uup8RhCSwYs

PS: This probably deservers to be a comment rather than an answer but it seems I do not have sufficient Stack Overflow street cred to comment. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I just tried one of those tags on my Samsung Galaxy S4, and it says they are "ISO 14443-3A NXP MIFARE Classic 1K - Not Supported."

But it still shows the serial numbers for them.

Using the app NFC Tools (free.)